# Linux Terminal: Finding number of lines longer than x

Tags: linux, bash, awk, terminal

I come to you with a problem that has me stumped. I'm attempting to find the number of lines in a file (in this case, the html of a certain site) longer than x (which, in this case, is 80).

For example: google.com has (by checking with wc -l) has 7 lines, two of which are longer than 80 (checking with awk '{print NF}'). I'm trying to find a way to check how many lines are longer than 80, and then outputting that number.

My command so far looks like this:
`wget -qO - google.com | awk '{print NF}' | sort -g`

I was thinking of just counting which lines have values larger than 80, but I can't figure out the syntax for that. Perhaps 'awk'? Maybe I'm going about this the clumsiest way possible and have hit a wall for a reason.

Thanks for the help!

Edit: The unit of measurement are *characters*. The command should be able to find the number of lines with more than 80 characters in them.

Comment: Do you mean `80` characters or `80` fields? `This is a test` has `15` characters and `4` fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the number of lines that are longer than 80 *characters* (your question is missing the units), `grep` is a good candidate:

```
grep -c '.\{80\}'
```

So:

```
wget -qO - google.com | grep -c '.\{80\}'
```

outputs 6.

Comment: You're right, I totally forgot to mention the units that I was trying to account for (I seem to forget one crucial piece of information when asking a question, no matter how careful I try). With that being said, `grep -c` worked like a charm. I was trying to do some brace expansion with `grep`. That didn't work out well. Thanks for the concise and efficient answer!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `'.\{80\}'` matches lines with 80 or more characters, so here it should be `'.\{81\}'`.

Comment: @ana-borges: you're right! (more in English is in the strict sense)

Answer (score 3):

[Blue Moon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27026147/827263) (in its original version) will print the number of fields, not the length of the line. Since the default field separator in awk is `' '` (space) you will get a word count, not the length of the line.

Try this:

```
wget -q0 - google.com | awk '{ if (length($0) > 80) count++; } END{print count}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
wget -qO - google.com | awk 'NF>80{count++} END{print count}'
```

This gives `2` as output as there are two lines with more than 80 fields.

If you mean number of characters (I presumed fields based on what you have in the question) then:

```
wget -qO - google.com | awk 'length($0)>80{c++} END{print c}'
```

which gives `6`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly as well. I did want to count the _characters_ rather than the _fields_, so thanks to @philbrooksjazz for catching that. I picked gniourf's answer over yours because `grep` manages to accomplish the same thing a bit more concisely for my purposes. Thanks!